# Reacting to ReactiveCommand in DynamicData collection

Tags: c#, reactiveui, dynamic-data

As I am trying to remove old implementations of `ReactiveList`, I find myself trying to implement a way to remove an item from a DynamicData collection when a ReactiveCommand in the said item is triggered.

The old implementation worked like this:

```
OldReactiveList
  .ObserveProperty(vm => vm.RemoveCommand)
  .Subscribe(vm => OldReactiveList.Remove(vm));
```

Is there a way to implement a similar structure with an observable change set from a DynamicData `SourceList`?
Everything I've tried so far seems to fail to either not knowing which item triggered the observation, or the observing relying on the observable property *actually changing*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cleanest solution I have come up with would be to modify the originally "empty" remove command to return "self":

```
public class ListItemViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    public ReactiveCommand<Unit, ListItemViewModel> RemoveViewModel { get; }

    public ListItemViewModel()
    {
        RemoveViewModel = ReactiveCommand.Create(() => this);
    }
}
```

And then use `SubscribeMany` to listen to these commands and get the item to remove from the list:

```
ViewModelList = ObservableCollectionExtended<ListItemViewModel>;
ViewModelList.ToObservableChangeSet()
    .SubscribeMany(vm => vm.RemoveViewModel.Subscribe(x => ViewModelList.Remove(x)))
    .Subscribe();
```

The `ViewModelList` could be implemented via `SourceList` or `SourceCache`, but the solution would be mostly the same. Only the way to access the change set would change.